# Arabic text to speech in Xamarin not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, text-to-speech

Hi I'm trying to develop an application that will talk to the user via text to speech. I have used the tutorials available on Xamarin website and the plugin created by James Montemagno and I can output English text to speech but whenever I ask the app to say Arabic words it goes silent.

Is Arabic TTS supported on Xamarin in either Forms, Android, or iOS?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested with other arabic applications on installed from the app store/play store?

Comment: please post your code to show how you are setting the locale and passing in the parameters for TTS.  The plugin is just a wrapper for the native platform TTS: iOS should support Arabic, but I can't find any clear documentation for Android about which languages are supported: it may depend on the device manufacturer.

Comment: @Slepz I don't know any other apps that to TTS in Arabic to be honest so I couldnt verify that. do you know any that I can check?

Comment: @Jason I haven't tested on iOS yet but it might work. I started with Android and it didnt work for me. I tried on my phone Samsung Galaxy S7 and on the visual studio emulator for Android 5" Kitkat 4.4.

Please find my code below:
Plugin.TextToSpeech.Abstractions.CrossLocale locale = new Plugin.TextToSpeech.Abstractions.CrossLocale();
                locale.Language = "ar";
                locale.Country = "eg";
                Plugin.TextToSpeech.CrossTextToSpeech.Current.Speak("هيا بنا نلعب", false, locale);

Comment: I would try "ar-SA" for language, that's the iOS locale for Saudi Arabia.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for getting back to me so quickly.. I tried with locale.Language set as ar-SA and I tried with Language as ar and Country as SA and both had similar result of not sounding anything. It sounds as if it tries to say something but then goes quiet.

Comment: One thing to note as well about Android is I tried playing around in the settings on my phone and in the emulator and I couldn't find Arabic listed in the language for the phone's TTS so I don't know if that's a limitation in Android itself as an OS which would be quite a shame. However I know that Google Maps plays the turn by turn navigation instructions in Arabic if your phone is set to Arabic as the system language

Comment: I'd try posting an issue to the plugin's github page, asking for a sample of using it with Arabic on iOS

Comment: @Jason thanks I'll try that. But the problem is that I still get the same behaviour of no sound if I use the native Xamarin way of doing TTS on Android as per the Android sample Text to Speech on Xamarin's website [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/PlatformFeatures/TextToSpeech/). I tried this sample by entering arabic words to speak it but I still get the silence as it happened with the plugin. so my worry is if it is not supported natively on Xamarin then it won't work in any plugin.

Answer (score -1):

After too many searches I found that android devices not supporting Arabic TTS and you have to use paid third party to do that.

Comment: Hi Mohammed do you know I can use or can suggest some of them I can have a look at? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alaa, 
after making fast search on Xamarin as I didn't used before .. I have found some links hope it will help you  : [Basic tutorial from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/text-to-speech/#Android_Implementation) , [TextToSpeechPlugin - github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/TextToSpeechPlugin) , [direct sample from Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/PlatformFeatures/TextToSpeech/)

Comment: For me as I'm using Appcelerator .. I can see that this library is very helpful for iOS as it's easy to work with Arabic & English perfectly but for Android as OS capabilities it's not supporting Arabic also.
For paid solutions check [this](https://www.ispeech.org/developers)
there is another work around you can do by sending your text to web service and get your response as .wav file then you can load it as audio file not text (Last solution :) ).